# Execute mysql command by Java + write out

Tags: java, mysql, macos

I need to execute mysql command by Java and write out the result.
But, only empty file created.

Execution environment is MacOS 10.11.2.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "mysql", "-u", "root", "-ppassword", "databaseName"};

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.from(new File("sample.sql")));
        builder.redirectOutput(new File("result.tsv"));

        try {
            Process p = builder.start();
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println(builder.redirectInput());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

sample.sql `select * from sample;`

when the main method executed, displayed redirect to read from file "sample.sql" on console.
And, result.tsv is still empty.

If I input `mysql -u root -ppassword -D sql2xlsx < sample.sql > result.tsv` into Terminal.app directly,
result.tsv is not empty, and writed expected results.

Comment: Why don't you use jdbc to do the same ?

Comment: Certainly it is a good idea. But, I want to know why command doesn't run.

Comment: Are you missing -D as a parameter?